# Problems to install programs

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, installation

I have started to work with linux this week, so I'm have some problems. One of them is to specifie The Python interpreter when i'm going to install a program. Because in the install guide say : "The Python interpreter may also be specified" how i do this?

Sorry for my english

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to install. But if you're simply trying to install software, then this isn't really a programming question, so it would be off-topic for the site.

Comment: but do you know how to solve it?

Comment: No. I said that it depends on what you're trying to install. Have you read whatever installation guide comes with the program?

Comment: yes, the installation guide says:                                                                 You need to configure SIP by executing the configure.py script. For example: -python configure.py
This assumes that the Python interpreter is on your path.                     The next step is to build SIP by running your platform’s make command. For example: -make
The final step is to install SIP by running the following command: -make install

Comment: So, are you typing `python configure.py`, and it says that `python` isn't found? Is that the problem?

Comment: yes, i don't know how to specify the python interpreter path

Comment: OK, first you need to make sure you have python installed. Does it show anything when you type `dpkg -l | grep python`?

Comment: yes, it shows a lot of things, but it's showing python, python3, python3.5 could this be a problem?

Comment: It's probably fine. Well... I'm a little surprised that python won't run. What happens if you just type `python` on the command line? (If it starts, type `exit()` to exit python.)

Comment: shows it "root@aeron-B85M-D3PH:/home/aeron# python 
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
"

Comment: OK, python is installed and working. What error message does it give when you type `python configure.py`?

Comment: it goes well ":~$ cd /home/aeron/Transferências/sip-4.18-2/
aeron@aeron-B85M-D3PH:~/Transferências/sip-4.18-2$ python configure.py
This is SIP 4.18 for Python 2.7.12 on linux2.
The SIP code generator will be installed in /usr/bin.
The sip module will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
The sip.pyi stub file will be installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages.
The sip.h header file will be installed in /usr/include/python2.7.
The default directory to install .sip files in is /usr/share/sip.
Creating siplib/sip.h...
Creating siplib/siplib.c.. [continue]

Comment: Creating siplib/siplib.sbf...
Creating sipconfig.py...
Creating top level Makefile...
Creating sip code generator Makefile...
Creating sip module Makefile... "                                                                              but when i type : make it's showed this :

Comment: :~/Transferências/sip-4.18-2$ make 
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aeron/Transferências/sip-4.18-2/sipgen'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aeron/Transferências/sip-4.18-2/sipgen'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/aeron/Transferências/sip-4.18-2/siplib'
gcc -c -pipe -fPIC -O2 -Wall -W -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o siplib.o siplib.c
siplib.c:20:20: fatal error: Python.h: Ficheiro ou directoria inexistente
compilation terminated.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'siplib.o' failed
make[1]: *** [siplib.o] Error 1

Comment: sorry for the mess in the messages, could you understand?

Comment: Yes, I think I got it. Does the installation guide say whether it wants python 2 or 3? Maybe you need to tell it to use python3. As for how to do that... can you find any help information for configure.py? Maybe try `python configure.py -h` or `python configure.py -?`. Maybe that tells you how to specify your python interpreter.

Comment: in the read-me that came in the folder says nothing, but when what you said it was showed this https://imgur.com/delete/sIA8E2gZ4n7YVsi , so i did this and the results remained the same https://imgur.com/delete/axfwtvi9Rkp1Bji

Comment: I can't see imgur files at work. Maybe if you ask at http://askubuntu.com/ somebody will have more ideas. This question is sort of off-topic here but I think it would be fine on that site.

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: Also, if you ask on that site, include the details you typed into comments, and anything else you've tried.